# Using the get method for an admin area plugin for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hyperlink, get, admin

I'm trying to use either the get or post method to transfer data over links in an admin page I created for a plugin, but whenever I use the get method to transfer the data to the desired page, the get information is transfered to *site/wp-admin/admin.php?name=somename&description=somedescription* instead of *site/wp-admin/admin.php?page=category-tag/tag-config-panel.php?name=somename&description=somedescription*, even when I direct the form to this.

Why is it doing this?

```
<form action="admin.php?page=category-tag/tag-config-panel.php" method="get">
    <table class="cTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Tag Name: </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="cTag_input" type="text" name="tName"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Description: </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="tag-description" name="tDescription"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="uibutton" type="submit" value="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here's example code using inputs, but I run into the same problem with the get method here.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the code you're using for it...

Comment: I added code but it's just a basic form to pass data and retrieve it on a certain page.

Comment: Did you use `add_menu_page` or `add_submenu_page` to create an administrative page?

Comment: yes I use those to add it

Comment: Is the form in admin area or in public area?